# how can we send data within modules in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-module

I am stuck on sending some small chunk of data sending from one module to another module. I don't store this chunk of data in query params or in some browser level storage or caching. What options are there for me or does angular has any mechanism to do that without reloading my application.

Comment: You can read official documentation https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but in the documentation, they have written about the component level data sharing that I can do with Input/output or service or Event Emitter there are multiple ways but here I am talking about two different modules.

Comment: you can use Services to send data.

Comment: @PuneetSharma Then you can simply import module in another module and used it or you can also use shared module. https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#!#shared-module

Comment: All modules have different services file like employer module have employer.service.ts and student module has student.service.ts

Answer (score 1):

Services are designed for same, (Dependency Injection)

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
//define a variable
someVariable = "xyz";
}
```

Provide this service in parent module or root module of the components (app.module.ts)

inject the service in components

```
one.component.ts
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {

}
```

// update the variable here

```
this.someService.someVariable = "Value Changed"

two.component.ts
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}
// updated variable can be accessed here
console.log(this.someService.someVariable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shared service. Then you can subscribe to that service in both of your modules and share your data.

for example:

this is my http service which is shared between the modules

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { APIUrls } from '../Enums/api-url.enum';
import { HttpResponse } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import { SessionStorageService } from './session-storage.service';
import { SessionStorageKeys } from '../Enums/session-storage-keys.enum';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _sessionService: SessionStorageService) {

  }

  public PostRequest(apiURL: string, body: any): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    let auth_token = this._sessionService.get(SessionStorageKeys.AUTH_TOKEN);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token
      })
    };
    return this._http.post(APIUrls.BaseURL + apiURL, body, httpOptions);
  }

  public GetRequest(apiURL: string): Observable<HttpResponse> {
    let auth_token = this._sessionService.get(SessionStorageKeys.AUTH_TOKEN);
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token
      })
    };
    return this._http.get(APIUrls.BaseURL + apiURL, httpOptions);
  }

  private _transformRequest(obj: any): any {
    var str = [];
    for (var p in obj)
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + ":" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      }
    return str;
  }

}
```

I added this service in **providers** array of **app.module.ts**

then injected this service in constructors of components in different modules

Comment: I was trying this but when i import the service in the module it was showing me some error.

Comment: can you share your code and error please . so that we can dig more in it.
Moreover Serivces are Injectable, they are put in providers list of module and then injected in constructor . we do not need to import them

Comment: okay give me some time... I will put the screenshot here..yes obviously I have set written them in both of the modules